# Issue with many to many relationship using code first mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I created two models of Class and Teacher, I want to configure many to many relationship using code first approach with two models.
When I add information into class and teacher tables, value not insert into TeacherClasses Table using many to many relationship Entity Framework code first approach.

Here code of models and controller below.

This is Class Model

```
public class Class
{
    [Key]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }

}
```

This is Teacher Model

```
public class Teacher
{
 [Key]  
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TeacherName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }


    [NotMapped]
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual ICollection<int> SelectedClassList { get; set; }

}
```

This is Teacher Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "TeacherId,TeacherName,JoiningDate,Salary,Email,Classes,Class,SelectedClassList")] Teacher teacher)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Teachers.Add(teacher);
            db.SaveChanges();

            teacher.Classes = new Collection<Class>();

            foreach (var classId in teacher.SelectedClassList)
            {
                teacher.Classes.Add(new Class {ClassId = classId });
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(teacher);
    }
```

this is image of database tables
[in database class, teacher and teacherclasses tables shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajLqH.jpg)

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FVLM.jpg)

This is View of Teacher

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Class List", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @*@Html.ListBox("SelectedClassList", ViewData["ClassList"] as MultiSelectList)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Classes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedClassList, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.ClassList, "value", "text"), new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedClassList, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? The image of the database table does not help. Try to be more clear and specific about the problem.

Comment: I have error that values are null in TeacherClasses table using this code in controller create action.

Comment: I am using multiselect listbox with many to many relationship EF code first

Comment: why do you add the teacher to its dbset and call SaveChanges **before** filling the classes navigation property?

Comment: What should I do? Can you set my code? Please

Comment: what is in teacher.Classes at the line db.SaveChanges()? is that the state you want to reflect in the database?

Comment: Can you post also the view, because I think you have 2 problems: 1 with the relation configuration and 2 with the view model and the way how you try to get the SelectedClassList

Comment: You should call db.SaveChanges() after foreach  loop as you will like to persist the Classes too, currently only teacher entry is being persisted.

Comment: madan, I have already call db.SaveChanges() after foreach loop.

Comment: Lucian Bumb, I posted view of teacher

Comment: did you add to the DbSet after the foreach loop too? because if the entries are not in the context, obviously there won't be any FK's added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description and the way you're saving the data there seem to be two possible scenarios you're trying to achieve:

1. Insert *new* teachers and connect them to *existing* classes.
2. Connect *existing* teachers to *existing* classes.

Whichever it is, the rule is always:

- First *attach* existing entities to the context
- Then *add* new entities

So for the first scenario that would be:

```
foreach (var classId in teacher.SelectedClassList)
{
    var class = new Class { ClassId = classId }; // "stub" entity
    db.Classes.Attach(class);
    teacher.Classes.Add(class); // Assuming that teacher.Classes isn't null
}
db.Teachers.Add(teacher); // <= Add
db.SaveChanges();
```

And the second scenario:

```
db.Teachers.Attach(teacher); // <= Attach
foreach (var classId in teacher.SelectedClassList)
{
    var class = new Class { ClassId = classId }; // "stub" entity
    db.Classes.Attach(class);
    teacher.Classes.Add(class); // Assuming that teacher.Classes isn't null
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

As you see, you never need to pull existing entities from the database. For creating associations all EF needs tho know is the ID values of the entities at both ends, so working with *stub entities* is the ideal approach here.

In the first scenario, if you don't attach the classes before adding the teacher, the classes will be marked as `Added` too, and you'll insert empty class records into the database (if they pass validation at all).

Comment: I guess in the last paragraph by *second scenario* you actually meant the *first scenario*. And in the second scenario links should be added after attaching the `teacher`, otherwise they will not be detected as  modifications.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, of course you're right. I had this all spelled out in a Stack Overflow Documentation entry, but yeah, Documentation was discontinued so I though I could quickly recover this from memory (which is always a bold assumption :) ).